# Play: How do you write a test for a model with file uploads?

Tags: java, file, upload, playframework

Play has a nifty file upload mechanism where uploads can be performed like so:

the model...

```
import play.db.jpa.Blob;

@Entity
public class User extends Model {

   public String name;
   public Blob photo;
}
```

the form...

```
#{form @addUser(), enctype:'multipart/form-data'}
   <input type="file" name="user.photo">
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
#{/form}
```

the controller...

```
public static void addUser(User user) {
   user.save();
   index();
}
```

Which is nice and simple, however I'm stuck on how to write a unit test for the model. How can I test it with a file that doesn't go through the upload process?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just create a new Blob();

Open a file on your disk (you could add a file in you project for this test)

And use this method from the play.db.jpa.Blob class to load the file in the blob.
set(InputStream is, String type);

Let me know if it works.